# How to apply upgrades programmatically in phpunit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, magento, phpunit, mage

I have developed module with sql script upgrade and after that my phpunit tests got not success, these break in place of call new attribute for customer.
I have investigated this case and concluded that new updates has applied after manual clean cache on the administrator page but don't after console command like zf clear mage-core-cache and etc. I think that runs anything else except cleaning cache...

Anybody know how to run check upgrade scripts like mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php and apply these programmatically ? I need that for my phpunit tests. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From memory its Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates(), but that relies on Mage_Core_Model_Config being initialized at least. It works through Mage::run() workflow.

Comment: Yes, i have found myself ;) thru Profiler. But it's not helped for me :(
Mage::run()... yes but for tests its resulting to halt test

Comment: it's my mistake .. i have tried without change version in config... it's work :)